# jQuery load an image and swap by click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code on start to call the main image:

```
$(function () {
   var img = new Image();
   $(img).load(function () {
       //$(this).fadeOut('normal');
       $('#bg div table tr td').removeClass('loading').append(this);
       $(this).fadeIn();
   }).attr('src', 'images/home.jpg');
});
```

Thats working so far. On click of an link i want to fade that one out and than load a second one in there. Somehow i cant get it to work... There are a lot of images that have to be loaded by clicking an element in the navigation, i´m not shure about the code. Any idea?

Comment: it doesnt look like you are ever hiding the image. Not sure what the problem actually is though..

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you can try something like this:

```
function ShowImage(src){
   var $imageContainer = $('#bg div table tr td');
   $imageContainer.empty().addClass('loading');
   var $image = $("<img src='" + src + "'/>");
   $image.load(function(){
      $imageContainer.removeClass('loading').append(this);
   });
}
```

And then call this function to show every new image.

Comment: so eg. if i click on 'a' i bind the click function and call "ShowImage". but how do i adress different images connected to different links in here?

Comment: You will pass path to image as a parameter to function

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a cleaner approach (sticking to jQuery)

```
$(function() {
    var $img = $('<img>', {
        src:    'images/home.jpg',
        load:   function() {
            $('#bg div table tr td').removeClass('loading').append(this);
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        css: {
            display:  'none'
        }    
    }).appendTo(document.body /* append wherever you need it */);

    $('a').bind('click', function() {
         $img.fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $img.attr('src', '/images/newimage.jpg');
         });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/AJcXd/

Comment: That looks good! Another thing i couldnt handle is than to unbind the click event (i gave the clicked one the class=active) and than bind again as soon another link is clicked. so i can ad and remove this class correctly, but dont know how to unbind and than bind again as soon the active class has been removed. any idea on that?